# How can things at the event horizon slow down and appear to stop to a remote observer?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, event-horizon

So they say the remote observer will never see anything fallen to the black hole, because any object will slow down as it gets closer to the event horizon and eventually stop to stay there forever. Am I getting it right so far? With this said, it turns out nothing has fallen to the black hole up till now. That is for us, as remote observers, anything that ever tried to reach the black hole got stuck at its event horizon. So we can go and see it right away - it must be still there. At the same time they say that the black hole keeps sucking matter. So question is, to a remote observer, how does all this matter fit the event horizon provided it will never fall through it?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21319/2451 and links therein.